# Kintone Add Record API required field error

Tags: api, postman

When I call ADD RECORD API of Kintone using postman

### URL

https://mysubdomain.cybozu.com/k/v1/record.json
with POST method

### Header

X-Cybozu-API-Token  => mytoken

Content-Type => application/json

### Body (Json)

```
{
    "app": XXX,
    "record": {
        "姓": {
            "value": "Olivia"
        }
    }
}
```

姓 is required field in my application on Kintone.

When I send request on postman

I got this required field error

```
{
    "code": "CB_VA01",
    "id": "hgmnVpwalK1Xl4Ebr3ss",
    "message": "入力内容が正しくありません。",
    "errors": {
        "record.姓.value": {
            "messages": [
                "必須です。"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It takes too long for me. Please help me!
Thank for giving your time.

#Kintone

Comment: Your current request seems to be fine, and I'm not sure yet on why the error is being returned. Could you update your question with screenshots of your Postman so that we can see the method, URL, Request body and response. It might help us solve the problem.

Comment: @will-yama Thank you so much.  When I try another app with request like this, everything is fine. I think the problem is on my app. In my first question post, I uploaded POSTMAN SCREENSHOTS but I think my screenshot images have been removed. I don't know what is the problem on my app till now. Thanks

Comment: OK no worries, as long as it's fixed that's OK. For future reference, it might be better to set fields codes with single-byte characters instead of double-byte characters. Double-byte characters still work with Kintone, but there may be issues depending on what tool you are using to make the request.